# JavaScript - Struct Arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on the below JS and it won't show an output when loaded.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>  

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var MAX = 3;

            function structCars() {
                this.make;
                this.model;
                this.color;
            }

            var cars = new Array();

            var makes = new Array (
                "Toyota",
                "Ford",
                "Chevrolet"
                );

            var models = new Array (
                "Camrey",
                "Mustang",
                "Nova"
                );

            var colors = new Array (
                "Blue",
                "Red",
                "Yellow"
                );

            for(var i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                var temp = new structCars();
                temp.make = makes[i];
                temp.model = models[i];
                temp.color = colors[i];
                cars.push(temp);
                }

            for(i = 0; i < cars.length(); i++) {
                document.write(i + " " + cars[i].make + ", " + cars[i].model + ", " + cars[i].color + ".<br>");
                }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The output should be something like:

0 Toyota, Camry, Blue

1 Ford, Mustang, Red

2 Chevrolet, Nova, Yellow

But nothing is coming up.  This could be something simple, or I am doing this totally wrong.  I am starting to learn JavaScript, and this is driving me crazy trying to figure this out..

This is for an online coding assignment and I don't want someone to do my work for me.  I have asked my professor, but he is only proficient in C#/Java and not JS.... thanks prof..

Thank you for any and all support.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) works without parenthesis.

```
for(i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
//                       ^^^
```

For the rest, you could use a constructor with values.

```js
function StructCars(make, model, color) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
}

var MAX = 3,
    makes = ["Toyota", "Ford", "Chevrolet"],
    models = ["Camrey", "Mustang", "Nova"],
    colors = ["Blue", "Red", "Yellow"],
    cars = [],
    i;

for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    cars.push(new StructCars(makes[i], models[i], colors[i]));
}

cars.forEach(function (car, i) {
    console.log(i + " " + car.make + ", " + car.model + ", " + car.color);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I removed the parenthesis and it worked.  I haven't tried using a constructor with values as of yet, but I will, looks much more simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Change length() as function to cars.length

```
for(i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
                document.write(i + " " + cars[i].make + ", " + cars[i].model + ", " + cars[i].color + ".<br>");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) method too.

Example :

```js
var makes = new Array (
  "Toyota",
  "Ford",
  "Chevrolet"
);

var models = new Array (
  "Camrey",
  "Mustang",
  "Nova"
);

var colors = new Array (
  "Blue",
  "Red",
  "Yellow"
);

var cars = makes.map(function(value,key){
  var car = {};
  car.make=value;
  car.model=models[key];
  car.color=colors[key];
  return car;
});

console.log(cars);
```